# AWS: "ssh: connect to host **.***.***.** port 22: Operation timed out"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, terminal, connection-timeout

Although my issue looks very generic and common, it doesn't seem to be identical to anything discussed here in stackoverflow. SecurityGroup has been set up with "MyIP" for ssh connection and I have been using correct pub IP to connect. Yet, I'm still getting timeout error as below. Is there something that I need to change in my Mac?

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % ssh -vvv -i ~/Documents/awsdemo/aws-livelessons.pem ec2-user@18.181.146.195
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 18.181.146.195 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 18.181.146.195 [18.181.146.195] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 18.181.146.195 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 18.181.146.195 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Here's my Security Group. You can see that it does have correct protocol and entered with my public IP.

[Security Group Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UIsd.png)

And I can confirm that it does match when I look up via terminal.

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com
"58.12.38.113"
```

And the EC2 instance does have this security group attached.

[EC2 Instance Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzIve.png)

If there are any other ways to troubleshoot this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you running your instance in non-default VPC?

Comment: Hi @Marcin.
Thank you very much for fast reply! 
Yes, that is correct. 
And I did following checklist to make sure if I've done everything correctly. Did I miss anything? 

* Has VPC been created - Yes
* Has Subnet been created and associated with the VPC you created? - Yes
* Has Internet Gateway been created and attached to VPC? - Yes
* Has RouteTable been created? - Yes
* If RouteTable created, Is taget of "0.0.0.0/0" set to the Internet Gateway that you created? - Yes
* Is the RouteTable created associated with 2 Subnets you created? - Yes

Comment: Have you tried setting sg to `0.0.0.0/0` inbound for ssh. Just to be sure this is not somehow related to your IP. Also have been playing with with NACLs? maybe you changed default ones to something that blocks the connection?

Comment: Ah!!! You hit the nail on the head!! NACL didn't have SSH! I can connect now! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I will make answer to close this question if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, please close.

Comment: I mean, you have to accept the answer so that others know that the issue is solved if you want.

Comment: Ah I see. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was due to use of non-default NACLs. The solution was to allow SSH in the NACLs.